# Robot Framework Selenium: control visible browser

Tags: robotframework

How do I use Robot Framework Selenium to control a regular browser that I can see, and that doesn't exit after finishing a test?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me at the moment unfortunately, can you please supply much more information so we can help out?

Comment: how do I run some tests, not close the browser, then run some more tests in the same browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You cannot get a handle on an already open browser. You can, however, open your browser with the test and then not close it. The browser will remain open for you to interact with it.

If you absolutely must have this functionality, you could try using the [remote library interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface). The remote library could act as a proxy to the selenium keywords. It could open a browser and keep it open for as long as the remote library server is running. My guess is that this would take a lot of work, and I don't see any real benefit in doing it.